# Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it

Tags: android, inheritance, kotlin, dao, android-room

Okey, so I tried to follow this guide: https://medium.com/google-developers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1
which led me to this code: https://gist.github.com/florina-muntenescu/1c78858f286d196d545c038a71a3e864

I tried to make my own example when I got the following two errors:

> Error:Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or
>   a collection/array of it.
>
> Error:Cannot use unbound generics in Dao classes. If you are trying to
>   create a base DAO, create a normal class, extend it with type params
>   then mark the subclass with @Dao.

I do not know if those two errors are related to each other, but I can't see where they occur and can there for not rule out that they are related.

```
@Entity
public class Data {
@PrimaryKey
uuid: String
title: String
}
```

My parent dao

```
@Dao
abstract class BaseDao<in T> {

@Insert
abstract fun insert(obj: T)

@Insert
abstract fun insert(vararg obj: T)

@Update
abstract fun update(obj: T)

@Delete
abstract fun delete(obj: T)
}
```

My subclass dao

```
@Dao
abstract class SubclassDao : BaseDao<Data> {

@Query("SELECT * FROM Data WHERE uuid = :id")
abstract fun getDataById(id: String): LiveData<Data>

@Query("SELECT * FROM BowelMovementEvent")
abstract fun getData(): List<Data>

@Query("SELECT * FROM BowelMovementEvent")
abstract fun getEventById(id: String): LiveData<Data>
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I was getting same error for

```
@Insert
fun insertCars(vararg cars: List<Car>)
```

I fixed it by removing **vararg**

```
@Insert
fun insertCars(cars: List<Car>)
```

Answer (score 5):

To anyone having the issue: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it

This error is an indication that a Dao utilizing the BaseDao does not have a valid class for that datatype. For example [here](https://gist.github.com/florina-muntenescu/1c78858f286d196d545c038a71a3e864) In this code the DataDao defines that class datatype to be used is type "Data" (line 23 of DataDao.kt) which is defined by the Data.kt class that contains the @Entity tag (line 22 of Data.kt).

So... if you are encountering this error, the error is NOT originating from the BaseDao interface but rather the Dao(s) that are using BaseDao.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S update all required dependency.It worked for me.

//lifecycle
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'

//coroutines
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4"

implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'


//Hilt

implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.43.2'
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.43.2'
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'


//room

implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.3'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.3'
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3'
```